# 8000 TPS in EOS

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions, private-blockchain

I have created a private network of 6 nodes in which 2 nodes are block producing nodes and remaining 4 are non-block producing nodes. I have changed block time from 0.5 sec to 1 sec.  I have to perform 8000 TPS so I posted 2000 transactions on each non-producing node but only 1000 – 1200 transactions get stored into the block. Can anyone suggest how can I perform 8000 transactions per second? 
I tried to perform transactions using javascript api as well as using cleos.

Comment: Why did you change blocktime? And maybe your hardware is just not powerfull enough to perform 8000 TPS... I would also not recommend using a private network with 2 BPs in production, for testing it is viable.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @TeeAttack42  Do you mean, if I use better hardware then I can perform 8000 TPS?  Also Does change in block time will help?

Answer (score 2):

If you need them all to be in one block, increase block time and max block cpu usage, and check you're using wabt and not wasm. All these can be configured in config.ini I believe.

Also ensure the action your calling uses minimum cpu, as you won't get anywhere near 8000tps for more expensive actions.